intellij creates duplicate files or directories
Since working on this project, I have seen weird things.
It happens a lot that files are removed at random (then I have to revert git), files are duplicated to 'xx 2.java' or now I even see duplicate directories of another projects and "project orginal/2/3" copies of the directory that I'm working in.
I just removed the project, cloned again from git, changed some things, build, and the .git dir doesn't exist anymore, project directory is duplicated twice.
I use Intellij 2024.2.
I know it sounds weird, colleagues never had this issue.

Do you use any cloud-based file syncing service like Dropbox or iCloud? They're bad for Git, do not sync repositories using them.

the parent folder of the project is part of icloud yes

That's the problem. Exclude Git repos from cloud syncing. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+icloud
